# Upload File from client on server "programmatically" using file name or "programmatically" assign filename to UploadFile Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

My question have two parts

1) I want to assign filename to FileUpload Control and then save it but the problem is that it is readonly

```
        FileUpload1.FileName="ClientMachine\\Image1.jpeg";
        FileUpload.SaveAs(ServerMachine\\Image1.jpeg);
```

Is there any other way?

OR

2)I have Full path of one image at clients machine. I want to download that image.

I searched on google but most of the question do it using ajax,javascript, multipart-form . i don't have any such knowledge. Can i do it purely using C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to do is, access a file at client's computer programmatically without any explicit action from user. its not possible for obvious reasons such as **the asp.net code runs on server and your file is at client**. There are obvious security reasons for why you can't do it.

You may create some sort of active x or silverlight plug in and run it in elevated mode, but then again, its not recommended.

[here's a similar question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1853310.aspx?How%20to%20read%20client%20side%20txt%20file%20content%20ASP%20NET%20C%20)